# Determine domain of double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

So I have a double integral $ \int_D e^{x/y} \; dA $ at the Domaine $\{(x,y) : 1 \leq y \leq 2 \text{ and } y \leq x \leq y^3 \}$

My question is: how do I translate this to the integration bounds for the two integrals.

I have written then domain in geogebra and saw where the two areas intersected, and this gives me: $\{1 \leq x \leq 8 \text{ and } 1 \leq y  \leq 2\}$

Is this the correct method? I am asking because I'm getting some wierd results when calculuating the integrals.
Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct limits. Please note that your region is $y \leq x \leq y^3$ and $1 \leq y \leq 2$.

So your integral is

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \int_y^{y^3} e^{x/y} \, dx \, dy$

Here is the sketch (you need to integrate over the region shaded in black) -

[image]

Comment: @AmyA Is this clear? Do you have any questions?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's very helpful. 1 <= y <= 2 makes a lot of sense when I look at the shaded area: lowest on the y-axis is 1, highest on the y-axis is 2. But how is y <= x <= y^3 related to the graph?

Comment: If you take a horizontal strip in the shaded region, it is bound on the left by line $x = y$ and on the right by the curve $x = y^3$. So we are restricted between these. If you take $1 \leq x \leq 8$, that means $x$ can vary between $1$ and $8$ for all values of $1 \leq y \leq 2$. So then you are integrating over a rectangle instead of what the question is asking.